# Differential of Elliptic curve with bad reduction

Tags: differential-forms, elliptic-curves

Consider the elliptic curve defined by the Weierstrass equation
$$E:y^2 = x^3+2$$
This defines a minimal Weierstrass equation for $p=2$ over $\mathbb{Q}_{2}$. It moreover has bad reduction at $p=2$. For the invariant differential on an elliptic curve, we know that it is holomorphic and nonvanishing. But what happens when considering the differential $\frac{dx}{2y}$ modulo $2$?

Is it in general possible that the associated invariant differential to a minimal Weierstrass equation for a prime $p$ vanishes modulo $p$?

Comment: You are right, I guess to make it well-defined we should consider $\omega_{2}=\frac{dy}{x^2}$. The motivation comes from considering the formal groups, which in this case gives an isomorphism between $E_{1}(\mathbb{Q}_{2})$ and $2\mathbb{Z}_{p}$. And the induced differential would be of the form $\omega_{2}=(1+\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}b_{i}z^{i})\mathrm{d}z$. But if $\omega_{2}$ vanishes modulo 2, then the obtained differential seems to be vanishing on $2\mathbb{Z}_{p}$, which moreover means that $\int_{2\mathbb{Z}_{p}}|\mathrm{d}z|=0$.

Comment: (being a non-zero meromorphic differential) $\frac{dx}y$ will usually have a pole on the (genus $0$) normalization of the reduction modulo $p$ of an elliptic curve $E/\Bbb{Z}:y^2=x^3+ax+b$ singular at $p$

Comment: As reuns says, at a prime of bad reduction the curve will have genus $0$, hence will have no nonzero holomorphic differentials. I suspect that you either need to resolve the singularity or look at the Néron model of $E$ to be able to rigorously study exactly what happens to the differential at a prime of bad reduction.

Comment: Is it still possible to make sense of the integral $\int_{E_{1}(\mathbb{Q}_{2})}|\omega_{2}|=\int_{2\mathbb{Z}_{2}}|\mathrm{d}z|$?